# session is working in cross browsers if I am not logout from wesite php

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am created website using cakephp. After I logged in(google chrome) my aplicaion, without logout I am able to open the same session in another browser(Mozilla Firefox).

How to handle session in this scenario.

Comment: Here I am able to access session with the help of session id

Comment: you are doing something wrong. sessions won't work cross browser, unless they share the same cookies and sessions (not normal)

Comment: In my browsers(Chrome & Mozilla ) cookies are saved for same login details.

Comment: you probably didn't destroy the session. There's no code that we can go on here.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your cookie time. If you dont set a time for cookies to remember your logged in then they expire when the browser is closed.
I would honestly set cookies for some decent time depending on what its for. Alot of people Close Browser Accidentally. A session is closed when you use `session_destroy();`

```
//if is logged in
$date_of_expiry = time() + 60 ;
setcookie( "userlogin", "anonymous", $date_of_expiry );
//another example
setcookie("email-".str_replace(".","_",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']),$email,$time_minutes,"/",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],0);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: When I first logged in(google chrome) my application, I am copying Session Id( say, Session Id = bj3ptts05e9e0qh0a6i4fqqaa0) from cookie in console( here I am not logging out from google chrome), then opening same application in another browser Firefox, and editing Session Id from cookie in console replacing  session id from copied one. Then I am able to see my dashboard in Firefox browser.

Comment: I solved issue Myself, While logging in I am saving session variable with user agent(in Google Chrome). while opening the application in other browser (Mozilla Firefox) by editing session id its checking user agent of browser. Its just not allowing to continue the session with same session id. 
--
Thanks every one.